# Is this an old C++ style constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

Here a piece of C++ code.

In this example, many code blocks look like constructor calls.
Unfortunately, block code #3 is not (You can check it using https://godbolt.org/z/q3rsxn and https://cppinsights.io).

I think, it is an old C++ notation and it could explain the introduction of the new C++11 construction notation using {} (cf #4).

Do you have an explanation for `T(i)` meaning, so close to a constructor notation, but definitely so different?

```
struct T {
   T() { }
   T(int i) { }
};

int main() {
  int i = 42;
  {  // #1
     T t(i);     // new T named t using int ctor
  }
  {  // #2
     T t = T(i); // new T named t using int ctor
  }
  {  // #3
     T(i);       // new T named i using default ctor
  }
  {  // #4
     T{i};       // new T using int ctor (unnamed result)
  }
  {  // #5
     T(2);       // new T using int ctor (unnamed result)
  }
}
```

NB: thus, `T(i)` (#3) is equivalent to `T i = T()`;

Comment: I think all your statements are correct.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: Note that the compiler will tell you pretty much all you need to know if you just ask it: Add `-Wall` and [you get](https://godbolt.org/z/H9CMbf) "`warning: parentheses were disambiguated as redundant parentheses around declaration of variable named 'i' [-Wvexing-parse]`" from clang, or the slightly less motivated "`warning: unnecessary parentheses in declaration of 'i' [-Wparentheses]`" [from gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/YmgUQv).

Comment: @QuentinUK thank you for this link. I was aware of it about functions (e.g. `T t()`) but not for so simple declaration expressions. For sure, this could be _vexing_.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The statement:

```
T(i);
```

is equivalent to:

```
T i;
```

In other words, it declares a variable named `i` with type `T`. This is because parentheses are allowed in declarations in some places (in order to change the binding of declarators) and since this statement can be parsed as a declaration, it is a declaration (even though it might make more sense as an expression).

Comment: So, is this only an interpretation choice inherited from C specifications where `int(i)` also declares an `int` named `i` ?

Comment: @PascalH. From a certain point of view, that could be true. Stroustrup wrote in D&E that he had considered an alternative, more intuitive declaration syntax for C++. If C++ had not had to be backward compatible with C, then perhaps it would have the alternative syntax, and thus avoid the potential ambiguity with expressions.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/) to see what happens in assembler.

You can see that #1,#2 #4 and #5 do same thing but strangly #3 call the other constructor (the base object constructor).

Does anyone have an explanation?

Assembler code :

```
::T() [base object constructor]:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
T::T(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-12], esi
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        sub     rsp, 16
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 42
// #1
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        lea     rax, [rbp-7]
        mov     esi, edx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::T(int)
// #2
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        lea     rax, [rbp-8]
        mov     esi, edx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::T(int)
// #3
        lea     rax, [rbp-9]
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::T() [complete object constructor]
// #4
        mov     edx, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        lea     rax, [rbp-6]
        mov     esi, edx
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::T(int)
// #5
        lea     rax, [rbp-5]
        mov     esi, 2
        mov     rdi, rax
        call    T::T(int)

        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```